# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run some Selenium tests using the ChromeDriver, and I started getting this error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129) on port 42985
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"7576.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.59)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.48 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
System info: host: 'SUJITH', ip: '192.168.43.228', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:683)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
    at Selenium.Test2.main(Test2.java:15)
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 20):

Please upgrade your chromedriver with lastest version.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

or

https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads

Comment: you can check here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: New site: https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/?pli=1

Answer (score 8):

If your chrome browser is recently updated to V54.0.x, then you might get this error. The solution for this problem is simply to update your chrome driver.

Choose chrome driver from the below link that will suit your system architecture.

[Latest Chromedriver v2.25](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, only my chromedriver and chrome browser has been updated to the latest. Can there be any other reasons as to this?

Answer (score 4):

This issue started showing up after chrome Version 54.0.x updates. 
Remove the older chromedriver from your path and update your chromedriver to 2.24. This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue . Updating the chrome driver solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to bare in mind for these type of cases:

- **Disable browsers auto update** - at least on your slaves to avoid these type of breaking your CI process. Link for how to on [Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates), and be sure to watch these settings on the installation.
- **Versioning** is the first thing to check with Selenium when it breaks all of a sudden. See [notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/notes.txt) for version compatibility.
- I'm using my own [Maven plugin](https://github.com/best-est/maven-web-drivers-compatibility-plugin) to check compatibility between chromedriver and Chrome version

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You might be using the lower version of the chrome driver.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception

I had the similar issue and was getting the exception as above. So always check the latest version of driver from here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I kept a Selenium script running for too much time than I **run out of disk free space**.

So, I just clean out the Temp folder and created a routine to keep cleaning selenium folders, and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error when your code looks like below:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

You have to setProperty first and then create driver instance next

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```