# Selenium SessionNotCreatedException:session not created exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, talend

I have a JAVA code iterating a list and looping session in Selenium and doing some stuff in JSOUP:

```
public static  String get_URL (String user, String password, String url) throws InterruptedException {
        ChromeDriver driver;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Talend\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        try
        {
        driver.get(url);
            WebElement photoEl=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@property='og:image']"));
            String photoContent = photoEl.getAttribute("content");
            ret_tag  = photoContent;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ret_tag = "no photo content";
        }

        driver.quit(); 
        return ret_tag;
    }
```

It happen before the loop finish I got this error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:session not created exception
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.119)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.13.0-32-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 601.12 seconds
```

I'm currently running it using:
V2.35 chromedriver_linux64
3.10.0 Selenium Standalone server 
Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit) Chrome

Is there any error in "throws InterruptedException" used in the function cause is a SessionNotCreatedException type??

Thx

Comment: I don't know anything about Selenium, but this path doesn't look good to me. `/Users../Applications/chromedriver`

Comment: This is purely a dummy path, program row are very limited to driver session iterating in a loop.after few iteration, on a valid URL, selenium raise above error

Comment: You can increase pageload time .. bec your web page is take more time to load

Comment: Hello Ankur, Timed out receiving message from renderer-> 600 it's about 6 min timeout, even that I've tryed: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067849/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-exception)

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be due to **incompatibility of your chrome driver and chrome browser installed** in your machine

Comment: To precise, the chrome driver version of 2.29 has the compatibility with google chrome browser of version 61.XXX

Comment: Hello, even update to ----------ChromeDriver v2.35 (2018-01-10)----------
Supports Chrome v62-64 I got exactly same issue/error message

Comment: Use this link as a reference to address your issue [some older reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067849/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-exception)