# Java error with Selenium and chrome session not created exception

Tags: java, selenium

I have the next error when try execute selenium test.

Before the chrome update all working perfectly, but now:

session not created exception

Log error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.544337 (8c0344a12e552148c185f7d5117db1f28d6c9e85) on port 36249
Only local connections are allowed.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544337 (8c0344a12e552148c185f7d5117db1f28d6c9e85),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 829 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:26:55.441Z'
```

I been try with other library version, chromedrive version, but allways is the same error:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your selenium webdriver supports the version of chrome you're using.Since you upgraded chrome your selenium webdriver may also require an upgrade.

Comment: Update with the most recent version of selenimum webdrive, the result is the same: error.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible duplication. I am pasting hyperlink here,since i don't have privilege to comment.

[org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067849/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-exception)