# chrome opens for a second and crashes using selenium 3, mac OS:10.13.5, chrome: 70, chromedriver: 2.43

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the below error:
For a second, chrome opens and then crashes again

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600229 (3fae4d0cda5334b4f533bede5a4787f7b832d052),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.02 seconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'kewm1584.noths.hq', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:417:93bd:2501:51d8%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.5', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

what else needs to be done to get this working?

Comment: It seems like the mismatch of the Chrome and the driver that you are referring to control the chrome browser, Do check the version once again

Comment: @Nityanarayan44 - I did check them and they seem to be correct. I tried with both chromedriver versions 2.42 and 2.43 that supports chrome version 70. Is there anything I need to check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067849/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-exception)

Comment: @miranmai, Please check your java selenium version also.

Comment: @Nityanarayan44 I checked all the versions and seem to have all latest. Java version: 1.8.0_181, selenium-java: 3.14, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay buddy, Try this combination with your `java8` :  `selenium-java 3.13 + chromedriver 2.38`