# While launching the Chrome driver I am getting "Session not created from timeout"

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

> My error is:org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session
>   not created from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer:
>   600.000   (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130) Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System
>   info: host: 'swati-*con-Mac', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10ea:7ed8:242:224c%en0',
>   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6',
>   java.version: '12.0.2' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
>   remote

Code I a am using is:

```
public static void initialization(){
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

        if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/swati/Drivers/chromedriver"); 
            driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        }
        else if(browserName.equals("FF")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/swati/Drivers/geckodriver");   
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        }



        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Create a wait. All test classes use this.
                wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);




                // Instantiate the Page Class
                page = new PageGenerator(driver);

        //driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
```

Comment: The code I am Using is:

Answer (score 0):

option 1:Change path till chrome.exe

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/swati/Drivers/chromedriver/chrome.exe");
```

Option 2:

> Use latest chrome driver version compatible with your chrome browser.

Option 3

> Refer old posts this might help you

[org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067849/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-exception)

Comment: OP is using _Mac OS X_, why do you want to suggest to add the `.exe` extension?

Comment: This issue get resolved once I updated my chrome to 80.

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        //Initialize ChromeDriver Instance.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\RPCPMAutomation\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
```

**"C:\RPCPMAutomation\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe"** - change this to your Chrome driver path.

Comment: This issue get resolved once I updated my chrome to 80.

Comment: Good to know :-)