# Web application cannot be launched with Firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I have given following code to launch the application with Firefox

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
"C:/Work/Assessment/Automation/Test_2/src/main/resources/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

I get below error:

> `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line`

I want to launch the application with the Firefox browser

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate. Instead of [40067849](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067849/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-exception) ("upgrade!" 2016 and for [Google Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), not Firefox), *[SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908154/)* (2020) might be more reasonable.

Comment: cont' - [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908154/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-expected-browser-binary-location-but-unabl/64908883#64908883) also references [three other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035303) [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000618) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322308).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have the Firefox browser installed
2. Use the Boni Garcia WebDriverManager
3. Update your Selenium version to the latest

Answer (score 0):

1. Please upgrade your firefox driver with latest version.

FireFox driver link : [Firefox driver download link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Note: Firefox browser version is same as firefox driver version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Firefox browser is updated so you need to update Firefox driver